error en reorganización genexus17 windows 10
gxexec "C:\Models\IOISEPPersonal\CSharpModel\web\bldReorganization.cs" -r:GxBaseBuilder.dll -arg:csc="C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\csc.exe"
Building bin\messages.spa.dll
Read in 1813 resources from 'messages.spa.txt'
Writing resource file...  Done.
Building bin\Reorganization.dll
"C:\Models\IOISEPPersonal\CSharpModel\web\bin\reor.exe" -ignoreresume
El proceso de reorganización no ha sido exitoso.
El valor de 'null' no es válido para 'stream'.
Failed: Reorganization
error: Error in reorganization
Failed: Run Home
